# Adding static data to kendo combo box

Tags: jquery

How do we add static data to kendo combobox?

Here is the code:

```
$("#CbxBusinessSegment").data("kendoCombobox").dataSource.add({ text: "PS", value: "3" });
```

I am getting...

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'dataSource' of undefined or null reference"

...error because of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#CbxBusinessSegment").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.add({ text: "PS", value: "3" });
```

in `kendoComboBox`,B of Box should be Capital.

[Example](http://jsbin.com/ebutaw/3/edit)

Comment: Thanks for sparing your time for me. It is still not working. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: pretty sure that there is some uppercase-lowercase issue.go through the example and figure out the problem or share your code.